# How to open a file in another window by clicking on a file in my window manager?

Tags: emacsclient

When I double click to open a file, a new Emacs session is launched, like this:

[image]

So now there are two sessions. What I want to do is that when I double click a file, it will be opened in another window in the existing session, so there is only one session. I know I can use `C-x C-f` to open a file, but the point is "double click".

I am using emacs 25.1.1, linuxmint 18.1. How can I do this?

Comment: From what program and what OS are you double-clicking?  Please also state which version of Emacs you are using.

Comment: Is it really a new frame in an existing emacs (using `emacsclient`) or is it a new emacs?  Can you switch to the other buffer from the new frame?

Comment: @UweKoloska, oh actually it was a new emacs, sorry for not clarifying these because I am new to emacs. I searched for emacsclient, and I found that it could solve my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run this in terminal (copy-paste it, then press `Enter`):

```
cat - <<EOFEOF > ~/.local/share/applications/my_emacsclient.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=my Emacsclient
Exec=/usr/bin/emacsclient --alternate-editor="" %F
Icon=emacs
Type=Application
EOFEOF
```

Then open your file-manager and change the default program for opening that file type(s) you desire, to `my emacsclient`.

This will open your files in your current frame.

Or, if you want to open your files in your current emacs session, but in another frame, run this, and open your files with `my emacsclient new frame`

```
cat - <<EOFEOF > ~/.local/share/applications/my_emacsclient_new_frame.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=my Emacsclient new frame
Exec=/usr/bin/emacsclient -c --alternate-editor="" %F
Icon=emacs
Type=Application
EOFEOF
```